# Set default path to check for reference links

Tags: phpstorm

I am a user of PHP-Storm and have been using it for years, the only issue I have ever had is the fact that phpstorm always tells me I am missing my reference links when I try to reference images, css styles, fonts, ect. I have looked for a way to set the default path for them but I can only ever find things related to document roots server sided.

My situation:

My root path on server for nginx: /var/www/html/app/vg/public
PHPSTORM deployment path: /var/www/html/app/vg
PHPSTORM local path: C:\Users\A\PhpstormProjects\VG Official Zend

The reason that looks weird is because I am using zend-framework-2

So a reference that works in the code looks like this: (ignore live links)

[image: error of non referenced links]

Answer (score 0):

Mark parent folder of the `/salute/` folder as Resource Root.

This can be done via

- context menu in Project View panel
- `Settings/Preferences | Project | Directories`

---

As for "live links" -- place caret there, <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> and choose `Download Library` -- IDE will download that file locally and will make new JavaScript library for it.

If you do not want to download them then I may suggest to just disable that particular inspection (same <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> but instead using <kbd>Enter</kbd> on "Download Library" item use <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> (or expand sub menu with mouse) and go from there with the right option.